# How to animate whole frame when clicked on button in xamarin?

Tags: c#, animation, xamarin.forms

I want to fade out whole frame when i click on delete button but i only know how to fade that delete button i have searched I cant find this specific example. In the example below will disapper just delete button and i cant find how to call whole frame to set animation on it.
button:

```
private async void deleteButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var action = await DisplayAlert("Delete", "Do you want delete picture?", "Cancel", "Delete");
        if (action)
        {                
        }   
        else
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            button.ScaleTo(1, 1000, Easing.BounceOut);
            var plane = (Airplane)button.BindingContext;                
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
            db.Delete<Airplane>(plane.Id);
            Refresh();
        }
    }
```

xaml:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Margin="0">
                        <Frame Padding="0" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light='#00d2ff', Dark='#121212'}" Margin="0, 70, 0, 0" CornerRadius="30">
                            <StackLayout Padding="20">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Airline}" TextColor ="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="35" FontFamily="Lato" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl}" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Plane, StringFormat='Plane: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Airline, StringFormat='Airline: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Livery, StringFormat='Livery: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Registration, StringFormat='Reg: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Airport, StringFormat='Airport: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='Date: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Comment, StringFormat='Comment: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Button Text="Delete" TextColor="White" CornerRadius="30" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Lato" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light='#00aeef', Dark='Black'}" x:Name="deleteButton" Clicked="deleteButton_Clicked" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.8, 0.5, 100, 50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
                                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Take a look at [Access elements of a DataTemplate from code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65671255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the code below to fade the frame.

In the button click event, we use the parent of button to find the frame.

```
 var frame = button.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as Frame;
```

**The whole code:**

Xaml:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding airs}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Margin="0">
                        <Frame
                            
                            Margin="0,70,0,0"
                            Padding="0"
                            BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light='#00d2ff',
                                                              Dark='#121212'}"
                            CornerRadius="30">
                            <StackLayout Padding="20">
                                <Label
                                    Margin="0"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    FontFamily="Lato"
                                    FontSize="35"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding Airline}"
                                    TextColor="White" />
                                <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                    <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl}" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Label
                                    FontFamily="Lato"
                                    FontSize="15"
                                    Text="{Binding Plane, StringFormat='Plane: {0}'}"
                                    TextColor="White" />
                                <Label
                                    FontFamily="Lato"
                                    FontSize="15"
                                    Text="{Binding Airline, StringFormat='Airline: {0}'}"
                                    TextColor="White" />
                                <Label
                                    FontFamily="Lato"
                                    FontSize="15"
                                    Text="{Binding Livery, StringFormat='Livery: {0}'}"
                                    TextColor="White" />
                                <Label
                                    FontFamily="Lato"
                                    FontSize="15"
                                    Text="{Binding Registration, StringFormat='Reg: {0}'}"
                                    TextColor="White" />
                                <Label
                                    FontFamily="Lato"
                                    FontSize="15"
                                    Text="{Binding Airport, StringFormat='Airport: {0}'}"
                                    TextColor="White" />
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                                        <Label
                                            FontFamily="Lato"
                                            FontSize="15"
                                            Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='Date: {0}'}"
                                            TextColor="White" />
                                        <Label
                                            FontFamily="Lato"
                                            FontSize="15"
                                            Text="{Binding Comment, StringFormat='Comment: {0}'}"
                                            TextColor="White" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Button
                                            x:Name="deleteButton"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.8, 0.5, 100, 50"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                            BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light='#00aeef',
                                                                              Dark='Black'}"
                                            Clicked="deleteButton_Clicked"
                                            CornerRadius="30"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            FontFamily="Lato"
                                            FontSize="14"
                                            Text="Delete"
                                            TextColor="White" />
                                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Air> airs { get; set; }
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        airs = new ObservableCollection<Air>()
        {
            new Air{ Airline="Airline1", Comment="Comment1", Airport="Airport1", Date="Date1", Livery="Livery1", Plane="Plane1", Registration="Registration1", ThumbnailUrl="pink.jpg"},
            new Air{ Airline="Airline2", Comment="Comment2", Airport="Airport2", Date="Date2", Livery="Livery2", Plane="Plane2", Registration="Registration2", ThumbnailUrl="pink.jpg"},
            new Air{ Airline="Airline3", Comment="Comment3", Airport="Airport3", Date="Date3", Livery="Livery3", Plane="Plane3", Registration="Registration3", ThumbnailUrl="pink.jpg"},
            new Air{ Airline="Airline4", Comment="Comment4", Airport="Airport4", Date="Date4", Livery="Livery4", Plane="Plane4", Registration="Registration4", ThumbnailUrl="pink.jpg"},
            new Air{ Airline="Airline5", Comment="Comment5", Airport="Airport5", Date="Date5", Livery="Livery5", Plane="Plane5", Registration="Registration5", ThumbnailUrl="pink.jpg"},
            new Air{ Airline="Airline6", Comment="Comment6", Airport="Airport6", Date="Date6", Livery="Livery6", Plane="Plane6", Registration="Registration6", ThumbnailUrl="pink.jpg"},

        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void deleteButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var frame = button.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as Frame;
        frame.FadeTo(0.5);
    }
}
public class Air
{
    public string Airline { get; set; }
    public string Plane { get; set; }

    public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
    public string Livery { get; set; }
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public string Airport { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :**
Give a `x:Name` to your `Frame`

```
<Frame x:Name="AnimationFrame" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light='#00d2ff', Dark='#121212'}" Margin="0, 70, 0, 0" CornerRadius="30">
```

**Step 2 :** Pass this frame in `Button`'s `CommandParameter`

```
<Button Text="Delete" TextColor="White" CornerRadius="30" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Lato" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light='#00aeef', Dark='Black'}" x:Name="deleteButton" Clicked="deleteButton_Clicked" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.8, 0.5, 100, 50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" 
        CommandParameter="{x:Reference AnimationFrame}"/>
```

**Step 3:** Recieve this frame in CodeBehind

```
private async void deleteButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Xamarin.Forms.Button button && button.CommandParameter is Xamarin.Forms.Frame frame)
    {
        // You now have the frame element 
        // write your animation logic to the entire frame now
        frame.FadeTo(0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: It writes "frame" does not exist

Comment: I can not write it more simpler than this

Comment: I dont have problem with that, I have implemented your code and it writes me frame does not exists, so I just want ask if you dont know where is problem?